# How can i group arrows/generalize in StarUML?

Tags: flowchart, staruml, dataflow-diagram, dfd

I want to group the arrows coming out of "Hammadde Dağıtım". How can I merge them?
I want to create a view like the picture on top.

[image: Question image.]

Comment: You might use StarUML but your pictures show data flow diagrams.

Comment: I am modelling a flowchart diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In short

There is no grouping function in StarUML.  You can align horizontally or verticaly the shapes, but nothing similar exist for connector lines. So the way is to go to manual alignments:

[image]

### Step by step

Since your connectors seem not to be fully connected, here a step by step explanation.  When adding a new shape (e.g. process),  select the shapes to be aligned,  right-click on on one of the shape,  choose `Format` -> `Alignment` -> `Align middle` ; then `Format` -> `Alignment` -> `Space equally, horizontally`:

[image]

Then click anywhere to remove the selection, and chose the flow connector tool:

[image]

Click in the center of the source shape and without releasing the mouse button drag the pointer in the center of the target shape:

[image]

When you release the button, you have an ugly connector. Enter a name or press enter or escape to exit the label entry.  Then select the flow with a mouse click to see the lmittle squares that will allow to fine-tune the layout:

[image]

Then drag the little boxes in the order indicated in red, following the movement suggested with the red arrows:

[image]

It's tedious, but once this is done,  you can move slightly the shapes, but as long as the horizontal line doesn't need to move, it'll still look acceptable.